# Bootstrap 3 Scrollspy highlights the nav element above the selected element until i scroll a few px down

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So My Scrollspy is working pretty fine. I have a one pager and when i click on a nav element it jumps right away for the correct chapter / heading. But then in the navbar the nav element bevore the selected one is highlighted. Say I have the nav elements Home, About, Contact. I jump to about everything fine - but that Home is highlighted. When i scroll down a few pixel like until the heading is vanished, is about highlighted. 
I have a fixed navbar, so i have a offset. 
Here's the JavaScript code:

```
var offset = 80;

$('.navbar li a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $($(this).attr('href'))[0].scrollIntoView();
    scrollBy(0, -offset);
});

$('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
    var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh')
})
```

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? What if you play with the offset?

Comment: Thanks! I played with the data-offset and got it :)